# JQ transform JSON doc

Tags: jq

I have JSON file with below format

```
{
    "key1": ["val1", "val2"],
    "key2": ["v1", "v2"]
}
```

I want to transform it into

```
{
    "key1": ["val1-v1", "val2-v2"],
    "key2": ["v1", "v2"]
}
```

How can I acheive this using jq in linux environment?

Comment: Are `v1`, `v2`, `val1`, and `val2` numbers, and `val1-v1` and `val2-v2` are subtractions? Or are they strings, and you want to join them with dashes?

Comment: these are strings. Just want to combine them with dash

Comment: Then use quotes to make it clear (also with the keys). Do the arrays in `key1` and `key2` always have the same number of items? Is this number always two, as in your sample?

Comment: Edited the sample. key1 and key2 always have the same number of items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `to_entries` to generate an array of indices and values. Use the indices to index into the other key, stored in a variable for reference:

```bash
jq '. as {$key2} | .key1 |= [to_entries[] | .value + "-" + $key2[.key]]' data.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/a4acVQHYZKJ)

If the arrays aren't big, you could also use the less efficient `transpose` filter to zip them:

```bash
jq '.key1 = [map(.) | transpose[] | join("-")]' data.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/VXq_Brl0bRd)

Output of both:

```json
{
  "key1": [
    "val1-v1",
    "val2-v2"
  ],
  "key2": [
    "v1",
    "v2"
  ]
}
```